# Microsoft Outlook Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I see who the attendees/invitees are in a calendar event that I was invited too?  Is there a way for me to see who else is invited to a calendar invite that was sent to me?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on your calendar icon (lower left) and access your calendar. If you click on the event itself, it should show all attendees in the lower right of the event page. Every person who was invited should have a picture below.

From there, if you click on the pictures, they will enlarge and you will be able to see their positions, contact information, etc.